# How to create timeout for should assertion?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress, chai

I need to wait a notification to be shown, something like this

```js
cy.contains('p', 'Data processing is completed').should('be.visible', { timeout: 120000});
```

According to Cypress documentation it is possible to customize should command for implementing timeout: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Wait-until-the-assertions-pass but to be honest I can't understand how the provided example can be used for my task. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you should do like this.

**JS**

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("p").show(); // Content you want to show
 }, 1000); // Delay you want to add, here it's 1 sec.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `timeout` inside `cy.contains()`, some thing like:

```
cy.contains('p', 'Data processing is completed', {
  timeout: 120000
}).should('be.visible');
```

As it is mention here in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Timeouts) `.should()` will continue to retry its specified assertions until it times out.

Comment: Thank you Alapan, that is the thing I was looking for

Comment: Happy to help @vitaliy4us :)